# Advanced Search web part giving error

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to add an "Advanced Search" web-part to my web-part page. Currently the web part is raising an error object reference is not set to instance of object.

Full stack trace recovered from SharePoint log is shown below:

```
AdvancedSearchBox class encountered unexpected error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox.GetScopeEnumerator(ScopeInformation & defaultScope)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox.CreateScopeRows(Table parentTable)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox.CreateScopingSectionChildControls(Table parentTable)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox.CreateChildControls(). 813aaaa7-5645-43b5-85ba-e8c67a57997b 03/07/2014 05:40:27.31 w3wp.exe (0x10D8) 0x0BEC SharePoint Server Search Query
dmz8 Unexpected AdvancedSearchBox class encountered unexpected error: System.EventArgs. 813aaaa7-5645-43b5-85ba-e8c67a57997b
```